# How to set radial-gradient with css in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

I have a Label. Try to set radial-gradient in my css for this lable.
How can i do it right?
If i set -fx-background-color: radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 50%, rgb(104, 163, 193) 0%, rgb(23, 56, 99) 100%); - I receive an error "mismatched parameters"
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

*Setting gradients for Shapes*

Here is an example I pulled from a small [clock widget](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2658491) I wrote a long time ago:

```
-fx-fill: radial-gradient(radius 180%, burlywood, derive(burlywood, -30%), derive(burlywood, 30%));
```

The gradient shows up as the circular shading on the clockface just below the center of the clock.

[image]

*Setting gradients for Labels*

As you are using a label, the corresponding css attribute to use to shade the text of the label would be `-fx-text-fill` for the foreground text and `-fx-background-color` for the text background.

Here is a sample with `-fx-text-fill` and `-fx-background-color` styles applied to a label.  The radial gradient used for the background is the same radial gradient that was used for the clock face.

[image: xyzzy]

```
Label label = new Label("xyzzy");
label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 180%, burlywood, derive(burlywood, -30%), derive(burlywood, 30%)); -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

*Actual parameters to use for your gradient depends on your application*

Of course, the configuration of radial gradients will vary depending upon exactly what gradient you wish to draw.  Documentation for the syntax an construction of an expression to assign a radial gradient via css is contained in the [JavaFX 8 CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and very nice clock widget. But i have got an error "unknown function" on - derive

Comment: When do you have an "unknown function" error on derive?  Is it at runtime? Or is it your IDE putting a red squiggly line under the derive function which shows up as "unknown function" when you mouseover it?  If it is the latter, then it is a failing of the IDE CSS analyzer and not JavaFX or the sample CSS file (for example Intellij Idea 2016.1 has this issue).  The derive function is defined in the [JavaFX 8 CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) using the syntax I provide and works fine when executed.

Comment: It`s in my IDE (Intellij Idea 2016). But -fx-fill not working when running program. Just white background in my Label.

Comment: Then the "unknown function" display in the IDE is a red herring and not a true error.  You have some other issue in your program.  When I run the sample program I referenced (Java 8u72, OS X 10.9.5), which uses the same `-fx-fill` definition I copied and pasted into this answer then the program runs fine and generates the screenshot image in the answer.

Comment: -fx-fill not apply to Label 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label

Comment: Labels use `-fx-text-fill` for foreground and `-fx-background-color` for background, `-fx-fill` is for shapes.  I updated the answer to reflect this info.  Sry for confusion.